# Grep exited abnormally with code 2

Tags: microsoft-windows, grep, find

Windows 10, Emacs 26.1

```
M-x shell
grep
```

here result:

```
grep
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

Nice.
Now I want to find files in temp folder:

- `rgrep`
- Search for - empty
- Wild card - empty
- Base directory - select current dir

And here result:

```
-*- mode: grep; default-directory: "d:/TEMP/temp/" -*-
Grep started at Tue Nov 27 18:55:02

find . -type d "(" -path "*/SCCS" -o -path "*/RCS" -o -path "*/CVS" -o -path "*/MCVS" -o -path "*/.src" -o -path "*/.svn" -o -path "*/.git" -o -path "*/.hg" -o -path "*/.bzr" -o -path "*/_MTN" -o -path "*/_darcs" -o -path "*/{arch}" ")" -prune -o ^"^!^" -type d "(" -name ".#*" -o -name "*.o" -o -name "*~" -o -name "*.bin" -o -name "*.bak" -o -name "*.obj" -o -name "*.map" -o -name "*.ico" -o -name "*.pif" -o -name "*.lnk" -o -name "*.a" -o -name "*.ln" -o -name "*.blg" -o -name "*.bbl" -o -name "*.dll" -o -name "*.drv" -o -name "*.vxd" -o -name "*.386" -o -name "*.elc" -o -name "*.lof" -o -name "*.glo" -o -name "*.idx" -o -name "*.lot" -o -name "*.fmt" -o -name "*.tfm" -o -name "*.class" -o -name "*.fas" -o -name "*.lib" -o -name "*.mem" -o -name "*.x86f" -o -name "*.sparcf" -o -name "*.dfsl" -o -name "*.pfsl" -o -name "*.d64fsl" -o -name "*.p64fsl" -o -name "*.lx64fsl" -o -name "*.lx32fsl" -o -name "*.dx64fsl" -o -name "*.dx32fsl" -o -name "*.fx64fsl" -o -name "*.fx32fsl" -o -name "*.sx64fsl" -o -name "*.sx32fsl" -o -name "*.wx64fsl" -o -name "*.wx32fsl" -o -name "*.fasl" -o -name "*.ufsl" -o -name "*.fsl" -o -name "*.dxl" -o -name "*.lo" -o -name "*.la" -o -name "*.gmo" -o -name "*.mo" -o -name "*.toc" -o -name "*.aux" -o -name "*.cp" -o -name "*.fn" -o -name "*.ky" -o -name "*.pg" -o -name "*.tp" -o -name "*.vr" -o -name "*.cps" -o -name "*.fns" -o -name "*.kys" -o -name "*.pgs" -o -name "*.tps" -o -name "*.vrs" -o -name "*.pyc" -o -name "*.pyo" ")" -prune -o  -type f "(" -iname "*" -o -iname ^".[^!.]*^" -o -iname "..?*" ")" -exec grep --color=always -i -nH --null "how_test" "{}" ";"
FIND: Parameter format not correct

Grep exited abnormally with code 2 at Tue Nov 27 18:55:03
```

Why I get error:

```
Grep exited abnormally with code 2 at Tue Nov 27 18:55:03
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are accidentally using the MS Windows `find` command.

You need to have a UNIX or GNU/Linux `find` command (and `grep` command).  You can use Cygwin, for example.  Or if you have such a command available already then you need to put such programs in your `PATH` environment variable.

See [this Emacs Wiki category page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryWThirtyTwo) for links to wiki pages about using Emacs on MS Windows.  See [this wiki page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Cygwin) about Cygwin.

---

Besides that, be aware that Emacs offers various Emacs `grep` commands.  So once you have available a working `grep` program you can use `M-x grep` instead of bothering explicitly with a shell.  This has various advantages.  See the Emacs manual, node [Grep Searching](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Grep-Searching.html) for more info.